# Comparison of multiple rows using a single identifier in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I would like to compare three columns in two different tables by joing through unique identifier.But my for single identifier there are multiple rows will be returned.

Example:

```
Table A

Identifier Flag1 Flag2 Flag3

1           56    36    46   
1           89    65    33  
1           56    89    22
1           11    89    65

Table B

Identifier Flag 1 Flag2 Flag3

1           56    36    46   
1           89    65    33  
1           56    89    22
1           10    89    65
```

Now i would like to compare these two tables based on Identifier 1 , can you please help me out if all the column values are matching i need update the flag.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think below code will help,
below code will update flag of table A for records whose column values are same as that of table b

```
update a
set someflag = 1
where exists
(
select * from B
where b.flag1 = a.flag1 
and b.flag2 = a.flag2 
and b.flag3 = a.flag3
)
```